# Issue with installing Ruby 2.0.0 with rvm on Fedora linux

Tags: ruby, linux, fedora16

Hi I started my adventure with RVM and tried to install Ruby 2.0.0

I run CS50-19 Appliance virtual machine on my Win7 PC

I have got this:

Error running './configure --prefix=/home/jharvard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',

showing last 15 lines of /home/jharvard/.rvm/log/1395728421_ruby-2.0.0-p451/configure.log

[2014-03-25 02:20:46] ./configure

current path: /home/jharvard/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p451

PATH=/etc/log50.d:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/etc/log50.d:/usr/libexec/lightdm:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/jharvard/.local/bin:/home/jharvard/bin:/home/jharvard/.local/bin:/home/jharvard/bin:/home/jharvard/.rvm/bin

command(4): ./configure --prefix=/home/jharvard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared

checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu

checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu

checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu

checking whether the C compiler works... no

configure: error: in `/home/jharvard/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p451':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details

And since I am with linux since 4 days I dont understand much of this please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install the compiler and supported dependencies](http://unclean.org/howto/gcchowto.html) and then go for the [rvm setup instructions](http://get.rvm.io). You might also want to look into rbenv as an alternative to rvm.